How can I specify actual type of T on a ParameterizedTypeReference<T>?
I have a controller defines following methods.

    Mono<EntityModel<Some>> readSome(...) {
        // works, simply.
    }

    Flux<EntityModel<Other>> readOther(...) {
        // works, simply.
    }


And, within my test class, I defined following methods that work.
    // WORKS!
    static List<EntityModel<Some>> readSome(...) {
        client...
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBodyList(new TypeReferences.EntityModelType<Some>() {
                })
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();
    }

    // WORKS!
    static List<EntityModel<Other>> readOther(...) {
        client...
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBodyList(new TypeReferences.EntityModelType<Other>() {
                })
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody()
    }

And I naturally defined following method for all types.
As you can see, it's just a generic method for all types.
    private static <T> List<EntityModel<T>> readList(final WebTestClient client,
                                                     final Function<UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction,
                                                     @Nullable final String accept) {
        final var responseBody = client
                .get()
                .uri(uriFunction)
                .headers(h -> {
                    Optional.ofNullable(accept)
                            .map(MediaType::valueOf)
                            .map(List::of)
                            .ifPresent(h::setAccept);
                })
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBodyList(new TypeReferences.EntityModelType<T>() { // NOT <T>, BUT Map
                })
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();
        return Objects.requireNonNull(responseBody, "responseBody is null");
    }

Now, when I changed the readSome|readOther method with the readList method, I see a weird behavior.
The Jackson does not parse the content into the  anymore, but a LinkedHashMap.
How can I specify Class<T> with the TypeReferences.EntityModelType<T>?

Try to make EntityModelType as a parameter of your method.
private static <T> List<EntityModel<T>> readList(
    TypeReferences.EntityModelType<T> entityType,
    final WebTestClient client,
    final Function<UriBuilder, URI> uriFunction,
    @Nullable final String accept
) {
        final var responseBody = client
                .get()
                .uri(uriFunction)
                .headers(h -> {
                    Optional.ofNullable(accept)
                            .map(MediaType::valueOf)
                            .map(List::of)
                            .ifPresent(h::setAccept);
                })
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBodyList(entityType)
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();
        return Objects.requireNonNull(responseBody, "responseBody is null");
    }


and then call it
readList(
    new TypeReferences.EntityModelType<Other>() {},
    .....
);

Hope it works.

Thank you. It works, but why? Why does it work? What's the difference?

Well. The  in the method signature implies that the method will be dealing with generic type T. This is needed even if the method is returning void. In your code your method doesn't know what is the T inside. You need to pass it as argument the way I showed you.
